# Create GraphClient with UsernamePasswordProvider with client secret

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created a desktop application that talks to Graph API (Beta).

In the development version, I deployed it on the application I created myself on Azure AD. As one of the requirements is not to show login dialog when using the application, I decided to go with UsernamePasswordProvider, which I provide the user name and password of my account and everything works fine (I didn't put client secret in my application).

When I'm about to deploy it on customer's network, I asked the admin and he provides me the service user name, password, tenant ID, client ID, and a client secret.

I tried using Postman to check if I can get an access token from those info and I can only if I provide the client secret along with user name and password.

When I'm back to the code, UsernamePasswordProvider's constructor accepts IPublicClientApplication which has no option to create the application with client secret.

I understand that there is a reason behind as the secret can be easily stolen if the application got decompiled but, if I'm (in fact, my client) not serious about this, is there any way to initialize the GraphClient by putting user name, password, and client secret together for authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important, the Username / Password flow is **not recommended** because your application asking a user for their password is not secure. For more information about this problem, see this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

If you still would like to use it, you could put username and password of that user in **Key Vault** and fetch those in your code.

```
string keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_NAME");
var kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var secret = client.GetSecret(secretName); // get username or password here
```

I recommend you to use [`ClientCredentialsProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider), it enables service applications to run without user interaction.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use ClientCredentialsProvider as the permissions I'm using are Delegated ones.

The user I'm going to use is one created just for this purpose, like a service account, so  it might not harm any real user.

I'll try your Key Vault solution to see if I can make it work.

I'm not sure if "convincing admin to remove a client secret" is an option here? I'm very new into Azure AD so not confident to raise this.

Comment: What do you mean "convincing admin to remove a client secret"? If your app is a public client, then the client_secret or client_assertion cannot be included. If the app is a confidential client, then it must be included.

Comment: I'm a noob in this area so I may misunderstood most of things. But from what I'm trying to achieve, creating a desktop app to call Graph API without the need of login while starting and need to use delegated permissions, sounds like it should fall under public client. But as I'm not the one who do the app registering (the customer's administrator did) so he registered it as a confidential one (guess from he gave me a client secret). Should I talk to the admin to change the registered app to public so it's not required any client secret?

Comment: I think it's better for you to use client secret, because client_secret is required for web apps rather than native apps. There is a [sample](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-console-up-v2) setting properties in appsetting.json with ROPC flow, it may be what you would like.

Comment: I think from the given link is **not** using the client secret? I find it uses public application  and authenticate with only user name and password. Or do you mean I **shouldn't** use client secret as I'm building desktop app, not web app?

Comment: If your app is a desktop **public client** apps, you don't need to use the client secret.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to convince admin to change the application to public client.